# Install layouts and templates from the theme divante

Tags: layout, blocks, theme, template, magento2.3

I installed the theme https://github.com/DivanteLtd/magento2-rapid-theme, the theme got up, everything is in order, I don’t understand how to set the main page to make it as an example.

The topic has a folder `Magento_Cms`, and in it the layout folder and phtml blocks. How to add them to the main page?

Added while blocks in this way:

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Cms::new-collections.phtml"}}
```

But I have a suspicion that the layout file `cms_index_index.xml` is not used and maybe these phtml can be applied at once and just?

Comment: You need go to content- theme- configurations and set this theme for full store ( default). After that reindex all and cache clean+ flush. If cms page is not working properly , go to content static pages and check therefore webstore view, enabled/disabled , colums or etc.

Comment: The theme works and is used in content configuration. The problem with the pages, such as the main. Here is the second your point is not clear. Setting the home page: https://monosnap.com/file/R0qPa8CYRtOsfNAlkfs2eAsvToiSEF
As you can see, I added blocks and widgets with my hands, maybe there is a simpler option. But the layout could not be applied because it is not in the list.

Comment: look at your screenshot, at label "Макет", set 1 column or 3 columns layout schema

Comment: tried differently, does not help.
in the end, we decided to check if the layout was applied, made a mistake, it works. He just seems to have a mistake.
And so that he was chosen there, you need to add as I understood layouts.xml then this name will appear there. And since it is just loaded automatically, since it is not a separate, redefining, but complementary, it works for everyone.